# Should we train base learners on same folds when we stack different models?

Tags: machine-learning, stacking

I am confused about k-fold stacking. Should we train all the base learners on same folds? I mean is it ok to do the KFold split with different seeds or all base learners should trained on folds splitted with same seed? Can you also explain your reasoning to your answer?

A follow up question is for the Meta-Learner, should we also train meta-learner on the same fold indices?